# get value from XML element nested in curly braces with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<UserItemInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Id>doej</Id>
    <DisplayName>John Doe</DisplayName>
    <Properties>
        <Property>
            <name>DisplayName</name>
            <value>John Doe</value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <name>User</name>
            <value>doej</value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <name>IAM_Email</name>
            <value>john.doe@mail.com</value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <name>IAM_Principal</name>
            <value>{
  "kind": "user",
  "alias": "doej",
  "status": "active",
  "isHidden": false,
  "lastLogonAt": null,
  "masterRegion": "local",
  "displayName": "John Doe",
  "name": {
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe"
  },
  "email": "John.Doe@mail.com"
}</value>
        </Property>
    </Properties>
</UserItemInfo>
```

And I try to get the `first` and `last name` value from the `IAM_Principal` element.
I was able to get the `value` element, but then I got stuck:

```
/*[local-name()='UserItemInfo']/*[local-name()='Properties']/*[local-name()='Property'][*[local-name()='name']='IAM_Principal']/*[local-name()='value']
```

Comment: Which language (besides xpath) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is JSON nested inside XML. A strange mixture. XPath 3.1 can handle it:

```
    parse-json(
       /UserItemInfo/Properties/Property[@name='IAM_Principal']/value 
    ) ? name ? (first, last)
```

Your only other option is to mix languages - use XPath to extract the JSON as a string, then use some other technology to parse and query the JSON.